# Cloo OpenCL c# Problem

Tags: c#, opencl, opentk, cloo

I am trying to get a simple Cloo program to run but it is not working, can anyone tell me why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Cloo;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


ComputeContextPropertyList cpl = new ComputeContextPropertyList(ComputePlatform.Platforms[0]);
ComputeContext context = new ComputeContext(ComputeDeviceTypes.Gpu, cpl, null, IntPtr.Zero);

string kernelSource = @"
 kernel void VectorAdd(
  global read_only float* a,
  global read_only float* b,
  global write_only float* c )
 {
  int index = get_global_id(0);
  c[index] = a[index] + b[index];
 }
 ";
long count = 20;
float[] arrA = new float[count];
float[] arrB = new float[count];
float[] arrC = new float[count];

Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
 arrA[i] = (float)(rand.NextDouble() * 100);
 arrB[i] = (float)(rand.NextDouble() * 100);
}

ComputeBuffer<float> a = new ComputeBuffer<float>(context, ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadOnly | ComputeMemoryFlags.CopyHostPointer, arrA);
ComputeBuffer<float> b = new ComputeBuffer<float>(context, ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadOnly | ComputeMemoryFlags.CopyHostPointer, arrB);
ComputeBuffer<float> c = new ComputeBuffer<float>(context, ComputeMemoryFlags.WriteOnly, arrC.Length);

ComputeProgram program = new ComputeProgram(context, new string[] { kernelSource });
program.Build(null, null, null, IntPtr.Zero);

ComputeKernel kernel = program.CreateKernel("VectorAdd");
kernel.SetMemoryArgument(0, a);
kernel.SetMemoryArgument(1, b);
kernel.SetMemoryArgument(2, c);

ComputeCommandQueue commands = new ComputeCommandQueue(context, context.Devices[0], ComputeCommandQueueFlags.None);

ComputeEventList events = new ComputeEventList();

commands.Execute(kernel, null, new long[] { count }, null, events);

arrC = new float[count];
GCHandle arrCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(arrC, GCHandleType.Pinned);

commands.Read(c, false, 0, count, arrCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), events);
commands.Finish();

arrCHandle.Free();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
 richTextBox1.Text += "{" + arrA[i] + "} + {" + arrB[i] + "} = {" + arrC[i] + "} \n";

}
        }
    }
```

This is the error the program gives me

> an unhandled exception of type
>   'Cloo.InvalidBinaryComputeException'
>   occurred in Cloo.dll
>
> Additional information: OpenCL error
>   code detected: InvalidBinary.

Comment: Have you looked at the programs buildlog? Does it say anything of interest? and from where is the exception thrown (I assume the commands.Execute, but just to be sure)?

Comment: In the end, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This looks identical to the VectorAddTest that is distributed with Cloo.

Are you using ATI Stream? If yes, this may be a problem related to this: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2946105&group_id=290412&atid=1229014

Clootils works around this problem by allocating a console. Check Clootils/Program.cs for implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

Change the kernel name - I think the name VectorAdd conflicts with something.